# Disable Visual Studio Code middle mouse select

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code on Ubuntu 14.04.

Is there a way to make clicking+dragging with the middle mouse button *not* select anything? Maybe my scroll wheel is a bit too sensitive, but I sometimes find myself accidentally clicking while scrolling. This is an issue because MMB-down + drag/scroll enters column selection mode, and MMB-up then pastes selection. This in turn makes a following change in my code:

[image] (before)
[image] (after)

which is super annoying because it usually happens when I'm scrolling a lot, so I sometimes don't even see that something has been pasted. In this particular case it was the Python interpreter who alerted me of a syntax error.

So, is there a way to disable the middle mouse button selection?
I would like to have a simliar MMB experience as in e.g. gedit.